# extract selected array values based on list php

Tags: php, arrays, extract, partial

I have a list of array keys in form of a string

```
"hasAddStrict,freqItems,freqAmount,freqUnit,freqFirstDayOfWeek"
```

Now, want to extract only those values, i.e $myarray['hasAddstrict'] should become $hasAddStrict, etc.

Is there a short way to do it? My rather dirty solution:

```
$ff = explode(',' ,"hasAddStrict,freqItems,freqAmount,freqUnit,freqFirstDayOfWeek");
    foreach ( $ff   as $key){   $ff[$key] =    $SERVICE[$key]  ;    }
    extract($ff);
```

Comment: tbh I don't think there's a better way. _BUT_ what hinders you to use the keys/values in the form of an array? It's better to keep them together and not to spam the namespace with a load of (maybe unpredictable?) variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Jeff that there isn't really a better way, and that keeping the variables as an array is probably a better idea, but you could wrap it up in a function for convenience (tested in php 5.6):

```
<?php

function array_extract(array $assoc_array, $keys_list)
{
    return array_intersect_key($assoc_array, array_flip(explode(',', $keys_list)));
}

extract(array_extract($SERVICE, "hasAddStrict,freqItems,freqAmount,freqUnit,freqFirstDayOfWeek"));
```

When tested as follows:

```
$SERVICE = [
    'hasAddStrict' => 123,
    'freqItems' => 456,
    'freqAmount' => 789,
    'freqUnit' => 'abc',
    'freqFirstDayOfWeek' => 'def',
];

extract(array_extract($SERVICE, "hasAddStrict,freqItems,freqAmount,freqUnit,freqFirstDayOfWeek"));

var_dump($hasAddStrict, $freqItems, $freqAmount, $freqUnit, $freqFirstDayOfWeek);
```

You get output:

```
int(123)
int(456)
int(789)
string(3) "abc"
string(3) "def"
```

Comment: That is very close. I was hoping php would offer extract ($array, $array_of_keys_to_extract) to keep it really short. For Jeff's proposal to keep the array, i.e. $SERVICE['freqFirstDayOfWeek'] I encounter physical restrain to type all the braces and quotations ... especially in an function where the number of variables is limited ...